# Is there any way to use Heading 1 in two different multilevel lists?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007

I'm working on my thesis, I have used a multilevel list for my headings each chapter, it works and I'm satisfied with it. When I'm numbering photos or tables, I previously used "Insert Caption".

After some problems, I have had to reinstall my Windows 7, and after that, when I continue writing my thesis, the insert caption numbering was reset. So, I decided to define a new style for photos and tables by multilevel list. The problem showed up when I defined a new multilevel list for figures that use Heading 1 for the first level and my custom style "figures" as second level. The Heading 1 in main text of the thesis multilevel lists switches to "no style".

Is there any way to use Heading 1 in two different multilevel lists?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can use Heading 1 in different multilevel lists. You can though use a different heading style that you're not using in the body of your thesis, say Heading 5 or 6 and define it to look any way you want. But, for figures and tables, I'd recommend using Insert Caption in the References area. You can then define different paragraph styles for these. Word has the built-in style Caption, but if you have figures and tables and want different styles for each, you are not bound to the built-in style. Use Insert Caption and then tag the content with a paragraph style you define.