# Two multilevel lists inheriting from same top level

Tags: microsoft-word

I am using a multilevel list to number my headings in a Word document.

It looks a bit like this:

```
1.    A 'Heading 1' heading
2.    Another 'Heading 1' heading
2.1   A 'Heading 2' heading
2.1.1 Something at 'Heading 3' level
2.2   Another 'Heading 2' heading
3.    The next 'Heading 1' heading
4.    Yet more 'Heading 1'
```

I now want to include a parallel list style that lets me number 'boxes' by their Heading number, but a different numbering scheme at level 2.

This might look something like this:

```
1.     A 'Heading 1' heading
2.     Another 'Heading 1' heading
2.1    A 'Heading 2' heading
Box 2A A case study or example
2.1.1  Something at 'Heading 3' level
2.2    Another 'Heading 2' heading
Box 2B Another case study or example
3.     The next 'Heading 1' heading
4.     Yet more 'Heading 1'
Box 4A A box example in section 4
```

Is there a way for me to set up a style (say, "Heading 2-Box") that draws upon the numbering level of the current section's Heading 1, but does not affect the Heading 2 and 3 numbering system?

I found this question from nearly 7 years ago that I think may have been aiming for the same thing, but it didn't get a successful answer:

[Is there any way to use Heading 1 in two different multilevel lists?](https://superuser.com/questions/498189/is-there-any-way-to-use-heading-1-in-two-different-multilevel-lists)

Comment: You could use the combination of STYLEREF (which picks up Heading 1 style) and SEQ fields (set to be upper case alphabetic sequence), in the same way as the caption does.  You could then just copy and paste that each time and refresh the fields after you copy so they update.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Tanya. Is there any way of incorporating a StyleRef field code in a style definition? Either a paragraph style or a list style would work, I think.